# How to validate Shipping Address is legit

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart

i have an online shopping site where a customer made a purchase and keyed in USA Street Address but selected a different country instead. Subsequently it was charged a wrong shipping charges.

Thus i will like to find out is there a way to prevent this and check if address is legitimate??

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Experian has a free extension to use their pay-service on Magento. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/global-address-verification-9218.html

We'll probably start paying this soon. We, too, are tired of lazy customer input causing us to pay extra shipping charges. One big thing that helped was requiring Zip AND Address match to the credit card in the US. (unrelated to question, I know)